# JPA validation: String in column should be accepted by java.net.URI constructor

Tags: java, validation, jpa

I'm using JPA to create a structure in a database. My task is to define a column with following properties:

- is accepted by java.net.URI Constructor
- ends with '/' (slash)

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Regards, 
Patrick

Comment: It would have been nice to show what you have done. Second, have you checked on validation api @Pattern? and searched for uri regex pattern on google?

Comment: you mean you want a Column in the datastore that is a VARCHAR or CHAR? and the question is? JPA is there to persist field values of a class. If you put a URL/URI as a field then any half decent JPA implementation ought to be able to persist and retrieve it

Answer (score 1):

Use JSR 303 (Bean validation). Use the `@Pattern` annotation on the field/getter and specify your pattern. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html

> What is Bean Validation?
>   Bean Validation (JSR 303) is a Java EE specification which:
>   provides a unified way of declaring and defining constraints on an object model.
>   defines a runtime engine to validate objects
>   Bean Validation includes integration with other Java EE specifications, such as JPA. Bean Validation constraints are automatically applied before data is persisted to the database, as a last line of defence against bad data.

http://www.jboss.org/ticket-monster/DataPersistence/